# Mqtt client does not receive offline messages from VerneMq

Tags: mqtt, mqtt-vernemq

We have an mqtt server (VerneMq on Linux VM on Azure) which is configured like below

```
max_inflight_messages=500
upgrade_outgoing_qos=on
max_offline_messages=1000000
max_online_messages=1000000
persistent_client_expiration=1w
```

in addition to it's default configuration.

In order to test the persistent message mechanism, we created the following scenario:
We fed the server with some test messages and wait couple of minutes before subscribing with the client (with cleanSession = false), we were able to receive all the messages.
But if we do the same thing and wait 24 hours, we can not receive all stored messages, even if we can see awaiting messages for that client with

```
vmq-admin trace client client-id=<client_id>
```

Broker and client both use qos=2.
Is there any other configuration on client or server we have to change?